CMake Static Library Package Configuration: Why is there a need for INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES?
Primary Question: Why do consumers of static library packages via find_package require the need to have all the dependencies noted in the INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property?
In my scenario, I cannot guarantee the environment that was used to create the static library will be the same environment for the consumer of the library. The static library uses target_link_libraries PUBLIC to link to several other static libraries that are pulled in via a mix of find_package and FetchContent. With that said, my original thought would be that the consumer would not need to have knowledge of the static library’s dependencies, but when I attempted to find_package it, it provided me the following error:
Found package configuration file:

but it is set to FALSE so package "static_lib" is considered to be NOT found. Reason given by package:
The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: some dependency.

Can the static library’s package configuration file be modified in a manner such that its consumers do not require its INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES? Or am I missing something more fundamental and I must have all of the linked libraries present in the build environment even for a static library?

In the configuration file of your library you need to add all IMPORTED targets which has been used when the library was being built. For that purpose you could use find_dependency macro, which will locate the dependent library on a consumer's machine.
